# Postman: How to view response of a previous request from history?

Tags: postman

In the left panel shows the History tab, which I can view previous requests I've made. When I click any of the previous requests, it displays the URL and key-values used, but doesn't show the response.

Is there a way to view the old response?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to show previous responses but not via History tab.

**What you should do is:**

1. To Save your response when you get it:
   [image]
2. To select in and click on it:
   [image]
3. Then you'll see your previously saved response:
   [image]

**Update**:

In recent updates Postman added possibility to view saved responses from History tab: 
[image]

Comment: Interesting! But I can't see the button "Save Response"! I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app to make sure it's up-to-date. Is it possible because of different OS? (I'm using Mac)

Comment: @evilReiko I have an idea! Make sure the request that you made is saved to a collection (or just saved). If the request is not saved yet, then you just can't save its response. Also send this request to get a response to save :)

Comment: As you said, the request must be saved in order to be able to save the response.

Answer (score 28):

In the latest app, v6.5.2, you can now toggle the `Save Responses` options in the `History` tab in the left sidebar. Once turned on, clicking on a request in the history would also show the response that was received for that request.

[image: Save responses in history]

Note that only requests sent after the toggle was turned on would have the saved responses.

Comment: I suppose you need to open saved request and there should be response tab

Answer (score 6):

There is an option in postman 6.5.2 in history tab. But it's unclear how to view such response.[image: history tab from new version]

Answer (score 0):

Postman (v10.21)

toggling this on would allow for **future requests** to be saved automatically.
Sadly older requests would only show the status code without the body of the request. unless you manually saved it

[image]